# discord.py client.get_user returns none with user id

Tags: python, discord.py

I keep getting a `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'` exception when I run this code
I have tried the similar questions and they did not work

```
import discord, os
client = discord.Client()
#on_ready
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('$test'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
        try:
          client.get_user(os.environ.get('bm')).send("Hello, how are you doing?"); #
        except AttributeError as err:                  # this except block always activates
          await message.channel.send('Err: %s'% (err)) 


client.run(os.environ.get('Key'))
```

Comment: Convert the id to an int, (not sure if it makes a difference but may work)

Comment: Are you sure that the ID you're passing in is correct?

Comment: yes also tried not as a environmental variable @12944qwerty

Comment: By the way, you do have to `await` the sending part... shouldn't affect anything since there is an AttributeError, just foresight.

Comment: changed that but still same error @12944qwerty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a old question where a comment on an answer said "`get_user` only works if the cache has it. use `fetch_user` otherwise"

Comment: Try linking the question here and accept your answer if it works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try if it goes like this. You're basically running an activity before the bot is connected and ready. When your bot first connects, it builds an internal cache of objects it knows, which is what `get_user` taps into

Perhaps the solution might just be to add a wait to the activity so that it waits until the bot is ready, so `await client.wait_until_ready()` under async def `on_message(message)` :

Try this:

```
import discord, os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.wait_until_ready() #update

    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    
    if message.content.startswith('$test'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

        try:
            client.get_user(os.environ.get('bm')).send("Hello, how are you doing?"); #
        except AttributeError as err: # this except block always activates
            await message.channel.send('Err: %s'% (err)) 

client.run(os.environ.get('Key'))
```

Let me know if it works now

Comment: @badge hunt  Have you tried this new solution?

Answer (score -1):

Add `await client.process_commands(message)`. Take a look at the code below :

```
 async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return
        if message.content.startswith('$test'):
            await message.channel.send('Hello!')
    
        await client.process_commands(message)
```

Try using this.

Comment: nope did not affect the error, it actualy gave the same error

Comment: Process Commands does nothing to the error